# termination request in scorm 2004

Tags: api, scorm

I am developing an API to handle SCORM 2004 , i want to implement the Sequencing and navigation algorithm .

in the SCORM 2004 handbook , they wrote :
"The termination process receives a termination request from the navigation process, and terminates the current activity. Depending on the type of termination request"

where is the termination request will be saved ? how i can read the value of the "termination request" in Terminate function ?

Comment: Are you writing a client API or a server (LMS) API for SCORM?

Comment: I am writing server (LMS) API for SCORM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Termination requests aren't necessarily persisted. Think of them simply as a parameter that is passed into the Termination Request Process. Which termination request is passed to the Termination Request Process is determined by the return value of the Navigation Request Process (you can't read them from the Terminate function).

You can find a list of the possible termination request values in section 4.5.1 of the Sequencing and Navigation book (I'm referencing SCORM 2004 4th Edition, it's on page SN-4-27).

You might also want to look at the diagram of sequencing pseudocode algorithms relate to one another available at http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/scorm-resources/reference-poster/.

This "sequencing loop" is executed in response to a navigation request. A navigation request can be triggered in one of two ways. Either, the SCO sets an adl.nav.request value through the run-time or the user clicks on an LMS user interface element.

In the case of the SCO setting a nav request, the Overall Sequencing Process will be invoked once the SCO calls Terminate. The nav request that the SCO specified will be passed to the Overall Sequencing Process.

In the case of the user initiating a nav request through the LMS, the LMS will first unload the SCO (which should cause the SCO to call Terminate) and then it will invoke the Overall Sequencing Process and pass it the user selected navigation request.

Comment: Thanks A lot Mike , and what about the postcondition and precondition when shall i test them ? and does this test required in the navigation and sequence process ?

Comment: And how the navigation process judges whether the navigation request is valid ? what is the value that i shall test ?